# Raspberry Pi, Ubuntu 20.04 server. Make sudo require a password

Tags: server, sudo, password, lamp, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 server image on a Raspberry Pi 4.
As per standard install there is no password requirement for sudo, this is something I most definitely want to change. I have tried already running:

```
sudo visudo /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd
```

and entering into it:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL
```

All to no avail.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try the commands if I can't get a suitable answer to setting a password for sudo. The rest: Well, I take that on the chin, you are right,  and I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Ah it is something we all went through ;-) sometimes Linux seems weird when it comes to things like this but it is always almost perfect when it comes to security :D I remember only 2 incidents: the fuckup where the nsa kept a loophole active for years and Canonical leaving the admin password in plain text on the system after installation :D

Comment: This is odd, because I also installed 20.04 on a RP4 using Pi Imager, and I'm asked for password for sudo without doing anything.

Comment: I just realized I have the file `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` which sets `ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`, but I'm still prompted for password. However, maybe this is the file that causes it? In any case, I'm removing this file on my system.

Comment: Yes, I just found that, and you are right, now a password is required. The only problem is that now, for reason unknown,  it isn't accepting my password, so it looks like I'll have to remove the SD card and muck with the shadow file to get it going again. However, problem solved, it's the 90-cloud-init-users file.